Список маркеров видимой области Yandex Map API 3 версия
Каким образом реализовать подобное на API 3 версии вот тут пример реализован на API 2 версии
Список объектов в видимой области

В API 3.0 отсутствует аналог этой функции. Чтобы определить область, в которую попадут все метки, нужно самостоятельно вычислять положение меток и формировать нужный bounds. Также получить bounds можно при помощи turf.js.
